# want to download file by id which is manually set in databse

Tags: php

In the database I have a table that is imageid and that image id is manually set there and every file I upload have their image id and I want to download it by that image id and all files I upload are stored in folder.

```
<?php
$owner = $_SESSION['name'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "filesharing");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fileup where owner = '$owner' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<p class="btn2">' . $row["image"] . '</p>'; ?>
    <a class="btn3" href="download.php?image=<?php echo $row["image"] ?>">Download</a><br><br>
<?php
  }
} else {

  echo "<p class='message'> NO files Uploaded yet! </p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What is your question?

Comment: my question is i in that above code i download my files with file name = image there, but now i want to download it by file id = imageid, which is manually set in the database..

Comment: (1).  pass the ID in your query parameter to the download.php and (2) amend your download.php so that it will download the image based on the db record ID.

Comment: but the other thing is all the files i upload are also saved in folder and i was downloading all the files by that folder by force download

Comment: i did this but i cannot amend download.php so that it can download files by id

Comment: Might help if you posted your `download.php`. Not sure where you're stuck though, you know how to get URL parameters (from your other (deleted) post), you can connect to your database and get data from your table. Do that in download.php (based on the URL parameter for the imageid)

Comment: but in download.php i cannot download my file i am able to download it but by file name not by file id .

Answer (score -2):

The link used to download should have the source of the file. If you want to download  `test.zip` you will have

```
<a href="path_of_the_file/test.zip" download>
```

In your case it will be

```
<?php
$owner = $_SESSION['name'];
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "filesharing");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fileup where owner = '$owner' ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<p class="btn2">' . $row["image"] . '</p>'; ?>
    <a class="btn3" href="{image_path}/<?php echo $row["image"] . 'exe'; ?>">Download</a> //
<?php
  }
} else {

  echo "<p class='message'> NO files Uploaded yet! </p>";
}

?>
```

Comment: in above i have mensioned that i want to download it by file id

Comment: What is the problem? Your have the id, with it you can create a link to the image folder, so you have your download path. Adding it in <a> will resolve your problem. What do you really mean by 'download by id', isn't what i've said before?

Comment: my problem is solved and i solved it by my self thank you everyone